# ConnectionRefused exception in integration test with subethamail Wiser

Tags: java, email, integration-testing

We have an integration test that fails in our test environment, but passes locally with the same configuration. (And of course, the developer responsible for it is on vacation--figures!) It's using org.subethamail.wiser to test an email notification.  The unit test works fine just by setting up Wiser to listen on localhost and the specified port, but the integration test can't connect. Is there another step needed?

Here's the relevant test code (simplified a bit):

```
private Wiser wiser;

@BeforeClass
private void init() {
    wiser = new Wiser();
    wiser.setPort(3025);
    wiser.setHostname("localhost");
    wiser.start();
}

@Test
public void errorNotificationTest() throws Exception {
    WebHookRequest request = getWebHookRequest();

    // modify request so that it will fail and set up headers - omitted because irrelevant 

    // Send webhook--the integration test fakes an HTTP request to a Spring controller method
    ResultActions resultActions = webhookValidator.hook(request, headers, new HashMap<>());
    webhookValidator.validateWebhook(resultActions, "Making sure we are able to trigger for dbid " + dbid);

    // wait for webhook to be processed and the email to be sent--changing wait time does not help
    Thread.sleep(120000);
    Assert.assertEquals(wiser.getMessages().size(), 1, "failure email notification should be sent");
```

The code that actually sends the email is

```
    private void sendEmail(MimeMessage msg, Session session) throws MessagingException {
    Transport transport =  null;
    try {
        // Create a transport.
        transport = session.getTransport();
        transport.connect(host, smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
        msg.saveChanges();
        // Send the email.
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.sys().warn("Unexpected exception thrown when sending webhook failure email. {} {}", ex, propsForLogging() );
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        // Close and terminate the connection.

        if (transport != null) {
            transport.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This logs the following:

> Unexpected exception thrown when sending webhook failure email.
>   com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,
>   port: localhost, 3025; timeout -1;
>       nested exception is:  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)  Email props: host=localhost,
>   mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false, mail.smtp.port=3025,
>   mail.transport.protocol=smtp, mail.smtp.auth=false,
>   mail.smtp.starttls.required=false

So it does seem like the properties are getting set correctly. And as I said, the unit test for sendEmail passes using Wiser, but in that case the code is called directly in the same process. Is there an additional step needed to inject Wiser into Tomcat for an integration test? The docs and examples I've read don't do anything more than listen on the appropriate host and port, but nothing I've tried works.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to this, in case anyone else ever stumbles over it: basically, the whole notion of using Wiser for an integration test was misguided. An integration test is running the actual processes, not mocks, and there isn't a way to inject Wiser into a running instance of Tomcat. I ended up bulking up the functional tests instead, using Wiser, and for the integration test just validated that it is able to send a test email without throwing an exception.